# Is it possible to pre-sort a text index in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

My understanding is that, in MongoDB, regular (not text) indexes are pre-sorted based on the parameters passed to `createIndex()`. For example, `db.collection.createIndex({ name: 1 })` will create an index with documents sorted by name, in ascending order.

Is it possible to do this with text indexes? I have a large MongoDB collection (millions of documents) with a text index. When I perform a text search on the collection, I'd like to sort the results by `created` date... but the sort operation always runs out of memory. Can I set up the text index so that it's pre-sorted by `created` date (ie. no need to perform a sort operation after the results are retrieved)?

Comment: Sorry I read the docs wrong it seems it's not possible "Sort operations cannot obtain sort order from a text index, even from a compound text index; i.e. sort operations cannot use the ordering in the text index.". And apparently sort on a text index is a real problem in MongoDB there are multiple issues on the tracker https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-26534 (and on Stack Overflow)

Comment: @sheilak Thank you! If you turn this comment into an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [text index docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#text-index-and-sort) it's not possible:

> Sort operations cannot obtain sort order from a text index, even from
>   a compound text index; i.e. sort operations cannot use the ordering in
>   the text index.

Unfortunately it looks like sort on a text index is a real problem in MongoDB. There are multiple related issues on their tracker [SERVER-36087](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-36087), [SERVER-24375](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-24375),
 [SERVER-36794](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-36794)